# Show asynchronous datas of subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I use a loop to retrieve the data stored in Firebase thanks to the subscribe function and forEach. When I do a console.log of my datas in the subscribe ("=== SUBSCRIBE ===") I have the good result, but when I do a console.log outside ("=== HOME ===" and "=== RETURN ==="), I have this result :

[screen of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9EqL.png)

I suppose it comes from the fact that it is asynchronous, how to fix this problem please ?

This is my code :

```
statut: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  statuts: Array<any> = [];

  // Données à enregistrer dans FireBase
  dateOfTheDay: string;
  dayOfWeek: number;

  constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase, public storage: Storage) {
    moment.locale('fr');
    this.dateOfTheDay = moment().format('L'); // Date au format : 04/07/2017
    this.dayOfWeek = moment().day(); // Numéro du jour de la semaine (Ex : 1 pour lundi)
    this.statut = this.afDB.list('/statut');
  }

  statusToShow() {
    this.statut.subscribe(statut => {
      statut.forEach(s => {
        if (this.dateOfTheDay === s.statut_date_tache) {
          if (s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false) {
            this.statuts[s.statut_id_tache] = s;
          }
        }
      });

      console.log('=== SUBSCRIBE ===');
      console.log(this.statuts);
    });

    console.log('=== RETURN ===');
    console.log(this.statuts);

    return this.statuts;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure. Once make sure `this` referes to the current class or not outside the `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: This is borderline exact duplicate, but the latter part of question is not, therefore an answer.

You are correct with the assumption that this is asynchronous, and as presented here [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2) you need to handle everything inside the callback (`subscribe`). BUT, here you want to return the response. You cannot do that, as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296015 it is not possible from `subscribe`.

What you can do, like presented in answer, you can use `map` and then return an observable, that you can subscribe to or use the `async` pipe if you want to use it in view.

Call the `statusToShow()` in the service from the component where you need it and subscribe to the value:

**Service:**

```
statusToShow() {
  return this.afDB.list('/statut').map(statut => {
    for(let s of statut) {
      if (this.dateOfTheDay === s.statut_date_tache) {
        if (s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false) {
          return localStatuts[s.statut_id_tache] = s;
        }
      }
    }
    // return something else if value is not found above
  });
}
```

Then you can subscribe to this observable in the component and you get the `statut` value:

**Component:**

```
constructor(private service: TodolistService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.statusToShow()
    .subscribe(statut => this.statut = statut)
}
```

I suggest you check the official **[http-tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)**. I know that you are using Firebase, but the idea is the same :)

Comment: Thank you, I try this. Where do I put the subscription ?

Comment: Replace it with `this.statut = this.afDB.list('/statut');` :)

Comment: I have my todolistService (Where is my statusToShow() function) and home.ts where I would like to retrieve my datas

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean :) Do you wonder about where to put this `return this.statut.map....` code or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: My service : https://pastebin.com/VDr13WpY, it's good ? And I would like to get my datas in my home.ts

Comment: Aaah, this is a **service** do not make requests in constructor of service. You can never know how long it will take. You should call methods from component, service makes the request and return the response to the component, where you subscribe.

Comment: I do not know how to do this :( it's possible to make a pastebin please ?

Comment: Updated my answer a bit, that should help :)

Comment: home.ts : https://pastebin.com/eW4dbp0B / Service : https://pastebin.com/KkKRDyzq like this ? :)

Comment: That looks pretty correct yes :) Are you having some problem with the code?

Comment: I have no error :) but how do I access my values ?

Comment: Well you have the value in `this.statusOfTheDay` in component, yes? or what do you mean by **access my values**?

Comment: Yes and when I make a console.log(this.statusOfTheDay), there is an array but it is empty :/

Comment: okay, well you need to debug your code and see why that is. Are you getting any data from db... and if so, check step by step where the data is "disappearing"

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help !

Comment: It is on the home.ts side that there must be a problem because I do not get my data in the array. What the function returns is correct, but not in the home.ts side

Comment: I see error now. You need to have some value in `this.statuts`. So whatever that is, you need to first fetch that data. the problem is in this line: if `(s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false) {` I don't know what that is in your code, but the error is there.

Comment: I asked a new question and it's solved :) thank you very much ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322698/retrieve-data-from-an-asynchronous-service-in-a-component/45323468?noredirect=1#comment77609793_45323468

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is, that `this.statut.subscribe(statut => {})` is a asyncronous function.

Your `console.log()`s outside this function has already been executed while the subscribe callback wasn't finished. You could do this:

```
statusToShow() {

let localStatuts: Array<any>

this.statut.subscribe(statut => {
  statut.forEach(s => {
    if (this.dateOfTheDay === s.statut_date_tache) {
      if (s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false) {
        localStatuts[s.statut_id_tache] = s;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log('=== SUBSCRIBE ===');
  console.log(localStatuts);

  this.statuts = localStatuts;
  return localStatuts;

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the function return void :/