# Retrieve data from an asynchronous service in a component

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I retrieve my data from Firebase in a function of my service asynchronously and I would like to retrieve them in my component.

I have data in my database, the function returns my data well but I can not retrieve them in my home.ts (array empty).

[image: Screen of console.log]

todolistService.ts :

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class TodolistService {

  statuts: Array<any> = [];
  dateOfTheDay: string;

  constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    moment.locale('fr');
    this.dateOfTheDay = moment().format('L'); // Date au format : 04/07/2017
  }

  /**
   *
   * @returns {Observable<Array<any>>}
   */
  statusToShow():Observable<Array<any>> {
    let localStatuts: Array<any> = [];
    return this.afDB.list('/statut').map(status => {
      for (let s of status) {
        if (this.dateOfTheDay === s.statut_date_tache) {
          if (s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false) {
            localStatuts[s.statut_id_tache] = s;
            console.log('=== STATUSTOSHOW ===');
            console.log(localStatuts);
            return localStatuts;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

home.ts :

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {TodolistService} from "../../providers/todolistService";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public statusOfTheDay: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public todolistService: TodolistService) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.todolistService.statusToShow().subscribe(status => this.statusOfTheDay = status);
    console.log('=== HOME ===');
    console.log(this.statusOfTheDay);
  }
}
```

I do not know where my problem comes from .. Is it normal that the "=== HOME ===" first appears in the console ?

Thank you in advance for your help and thank you to @AJT_82.

Comment: So are you asking how to return any objects, where the ID is not already stored in `statuts` and the date matches?

Comment: I would like to get the same result that returns "=== STATUSTOSHOW ===" in my component home.ts because it is empty and I don't understand why

Comment: I think it's because you're using your map wrong - I'll try and write an answer now

Comment: console.log(this.statusOfTheDay); use it inside the subscribe

Comment: Thanks you. But why would the problem come from the map ? Because the result returned by my function is correct, it's just in the home.ts that I do not retrieve the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are not returning anything from your `.map`. You could also make it simpler with a filter statement.

```js
return this.afDB.list('/statut').map(status => {
  return status.filter(s => this.dateOfTheDay === s.statut_date_tache && (s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false));
});
```

If you still want to log out the status as it is selected you could use

```js
return this.afDB.list('/statut').map(status => {
  return status.filter(s => {
    if (this.dateOfTheDay === s.statut_date_tache && (s.statut_id_tache in this.statuts === false))) {
      console.log (s);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

You also need to wait for the `subscribe` to finish before logging

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.todolistService.statusToShow().subscribe(status => {
    this.statusOfTheDay = status;
    console.log('=== HOME ===');
    console.log(this.statusOfTheDay);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my home.ts is still empty : []

Comment: actually ... I can't believe I didn't notice where you were logging it - I'll update answer

Comment: It's possible to push s in localStatuts[s.statut_id_tache] ?

Comment: Yes, along with the `console.log` in the second code block add any other code you might need. You can also chain observable sequences with [do](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) which might make your code cleaner