# Making request to firebase realtime database and filtering result with angular pipe

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ngfor

I have a web app that makes a request to firebase realtime database for user information.

The info is returned when the service calls the method below:

```
//searches db for user information
getUserInfo(uid){
    return this.db.list('users/', ref => ref.orderByKey().equalTo(uid)).valueChanges();
}
```

This method is triggered inside a pipe defined like so:

```
@Pipe({
 name: 'usernamePipe'
})

export class UsernameFilter implements PipeTransform{

constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService){
}

transform(uid: any):any {

//return item if neither filter nor list exists
if(!uid){
  return uid;
}

var user = {};

this.auth.getUserInfo(uid)
  .subscribe(res => {
    user = res;
    return user[0].userInfo.firstName;
  })
 }
}
```

The pipe is used on a list of messages obtained by a call to my realtime database inside my component like so:

```
<div class="message-summary" *ngFor="let msg of messageThread.messages | keys; let last = last" (click)="getThreadDetails(messageThread.messages)">
    <span class="time">{{msg.timeSent | date: 'short'}}</span>
    <span class="sender-name" *ngIf="msg.from !== 'admin'">{{msg.from | usernamePipe | async}}</span>
</div>
```

The `keys` pipe is another custom pipe I used to turn the objects returned from the initial request to the realtime database into an array in order to iterate over with `*ngFor`

Issue is that the transformed data doesn't show up in the DOM but if I try logging it to console, it shows up - proving that the method works but it's not displaying for some reason.

Comment: one problem in your code... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295854/angular-2-how-to-return-data-from-subscribe

Comment: Sorry what's the problem you speak of?

Comment: From what I can see, you are trying to return data from `subscribe`.

Comment: Yes you're right about that, but trying to return from `.map` doesn't work either. I tried swapping out the `.subscribe` for `.map` and kept everything else the same but didn't get a change in the DOM either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the pipe to code below, getting rid of the subscribe and extras seemed to do the trick. Also the async **has** to be included after calling the pipe in the DOM or else nothing shows up.

```
return this.auth.getUserInfo(uid);
```

Hope someone finds this useful, feel free to message me if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are performing an asyncrhonous task and you are waiting it to be accomplished in order to change a value.

If it was inside a **Component**, you would see the value changed because of *change detection* strategy, but in this case it is inside a **Pipe** and pipes work differently.

From [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) :

> Angular looks for changes to data-bound values through a change detection process that runs after every DOM event: every keystroke, mouse move, timer tick, and server response. This could be expensive. Angular strives to lower the cost whenever possible and appropriate.
>   Angular picks a simpler, faster change detection algorithm when you use a pipe.

So the value changes but the view isn't updated because the *Change Detection* isn't performed.

To perform a full change detection cycle also in case of events that happen inside a **Pipe** you can transform your current pipe into an [impure pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#impure-pipes) just adding a field in the metadata:

```
@Pipe({
 name: 'usernamePipe',
 pure: false
})
```

Comment: Yea I tried that, but it doesn't update the DOM either

Comment: Can you provide a plunker? Maybe the problem is elsewhere