# typescript/angular pass value out of this?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So in normal javascript if I wanted to assign a value to a variable and then use that value outside of a function it would be done by declaring the variable first and then define it's value in the function. I'm brand new to typescript and angular so I am missing how to do this.

In the code below I am trying to get the value from a method in a service and then pass that value into my return. (I hope that makes sense). However I keep getting undefined on `console.log(url)` with no other errors.

```
emailsAPI() {
    let url: any  
    this.apiUrlsService.urlsAPI().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.results = data
            url = this.results.emails
        }
    );
    console.log(url)
    return this.http.get('assets/api/email_list.json')
}
```

api-urls service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiUrlsService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    urlsAPI () {
        return this.http.get('assets/api/api_urls.json')
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295854/angular-2-how-to-return-data-from-subscribe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2

Comment: What is the purpose of sending http get request ?
The point from where you are calling this service do you want the emails or the result of httpget?

Comment: @AnkitKapoor so basically I have a json file which contains all the available api urls. in each of the services i build I first need to get the url from the data_urls.json and then use that url to produce an httpget result. in this case it would be the emails._list.json

Comment: Ok got it. So what do you want from the emailsAPI method? I mean you got the email URL from data_url.json . Now you just want to get the result from this email_url.json right?

Comment: yes that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per reactive programming, this is the expected behaviour you are getting. As subscribe method is async due to which you are getting result later on when data is received. But your console log is called in sync thread so it called as soon as you are defining subscribe method. If you want the console to get printed. Put it inside your subscribe data block.

**UPDATE:**

As per your requirement, you should return Subject instead of Observable as Subject being data consumer as well as data producer. So it will consume data from httpget request from email and act as a producer in the method from where you called emailsAPI method.

```
emailsAPI(): Subject<any> {
    let emailSubject:Subject = new Subject();  
    this.apiUrlsService.urlsAPI()
        .flatMap(data => {
            this.results = data
            return this.results.emails;
        }).
        subscribe(url=> {
        this.http.get(your_email_url_from_url_received).subscribe(emailSubject);   
   });
    return emailSubject;
}
```

The subject can be subscribed same as you will be doing with Observable in your calee method.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling async method `subscribe` and then trying to log the coming value before subscription is resolved. Put last two statements (console.log and return) inside the curly braces just after assigning `this.results.emails` to the `url` variable

Comment: i did this and get this error: ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(19,37): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: You need to add return type in your `urlsAPI` function declaration (it should return Observable).

Comment: OK. So now change it to:
   ```urlsAPI():Observable<any> {
        ```return this.http.get('assets/api/api_urls.json')
   ``` }

Answer (score 1):

```
emailsAPI(): Observable<any> {
    let url: any  
    return this.apiUrlsService.urlsAPI()
        .flatMap(data => {
            this.results = data
            url = this.results.emails
            // you can now access url variable
            return this.http.get('assets/api/email_list.json')
        });

}
```

Comment: where do I import flatMap from? import 'rxjs/add/operator/flatMap'; does not seem to do the trick?

Comment: @SandraWillford `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` mergeMap is an alias for flatMap

Comment: i did this and get this error: ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(19,37): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: where are you using `subscribe` ?

Comment: in my component where I pass use this method in: 'this.getEmailsService.emailsAPI().subscribe(
   data => {
    this.results = data
    this.emails = this.results
   }
  );'

Comment: that's because you are not returning anything from `emailsAPI` method. return the `observable` instance as per my edited answer.