# Load Ionic alert with firebase list data

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

the question is clear, I need to display an alert with the elements of a firebase list.

> **Alert creation**

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Elegir repartidor',
      inputs: [],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Asignar',
          handler: data => {
              this.firebaseService.updateOrderAssignDeliverymen(orderKey, data);
              },
          role: 'cancel'
        }
      ]
    });
    this.firebaseService.getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert).then(res => alert.present());
```

> **Alert Inputs creation**

```
getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert: AlertController) {
    this.afd.list('/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('role').equalTo('Repartidor'))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe( res =>
        res.map(action => {
          alert.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: action.payload.val().name,
            value: action.key
          })
        }),
        error => console.log(error));
  }
```

After reading many questions, quite surprised about the number of different approaches... and more surprised that I haven't been able to success with one.

> **First attempt**

Created a second function with a simple promise return to try. Everything is working ok.

```
getDeliveryMenFillAlert2(alert: AlertController) {
return Promise.resolve(true);
//return Promise.reject(false);
```

}

```
this.firebaseService.getDeliveryMenFillAlert2(alert)
  .then(resolve => console.log('Resolve: ' + resolve),
        reject => console.log('Reject: ' + reject));
```

> **Second attempt**

Tried to insert this simple return in my original function an of course change the call to this original function.

```
getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert: AlertController) {
this.afd.list('/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('role').equalTo('Repartidor'))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe( res =>
    res.map(action => {
      alert.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: action.payload.val().name,
        value: action.key
      });
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }),
  error => {
    console.log(error)
    return Promise.reject(false);
  });
```

}

But an error is thrown "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

> **Third attempt**

Added return Promise to the function. Same error.

```
getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert: AlertController): Promise {
```

**Fourth attempt**
Reading one of the questions it introduced the async/await concept, so I introduced "async" to the function and "await" to the response.

```
async getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert: AlertController): Promise {

return await Promise.resolve(true);
```

Recibe another error "Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: The keyword 'yield' is reserved".

> **Last try**

Don't know why but just deleted "await" but keeping "async" in the function, it doesn't retrieve any error (great) but the console.log of the call prints "Resolve: undefined".

So it seems that is resolving but doesn't work.

I also tried to return "new Promise..." and "true.toPromise()" instead of "return Promise.resolve(true)", I read it somewhere but nothing is working. Any help please, I'm trying hard but not able to.

**FINAL SOLUTION** (can't post it as response)

```
getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert: AlertController) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.afd.list('/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('role').equalTo('Repartidor'))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe( res =>
        res.map(action => {
          alert.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: action.payload.val().name,
            value: action.key
          });
          resolve(alert);
        }))
      });
   }
```

and the call would be:

```
this.firebaseService.getDeliveryMenFillAlert2(alert)
      .then(resolve => alert.present());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling `alert.present()` just after this call :

```
this.firebaseService.getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert);
```

If so, you probably want to wait for your callback to end before displaying the alert.

- A **quick fix** could be to present the alert after setting the `inputs` :

```js
alert.addInput({
  type: 'radio',
  label: action.payload.val().name,
  value: action.key
});
alert.present();
```

- But a **better** way would be to return a *promise* from your `getDeliveryMenFillAlert` function. And call `alert.present()` in the sucess callback :

```js
this.firebaseService.getDeliveryMenFillAlert(alert)
    .then(res => alert.present());
```

Comment: First approach working (great) but as you recommend I want to use the better way.

I guess that here I don't really need to return any data, so "res" is unuseful. Watching other questions to learn promises I have tried to

   return new Promise(true);
   return new Promise((res) => { res(true); });

But it's throwing the error "Cannot read property then of undefined", what should I return ¿?

Comment: You should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to learn about promises.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296015/9425100) explain how to deal with _observable_, instead of wrapping your function in a _promise_ as I suggested.

Comment: Your link and many other questions and videos about promises already readen, will write an answer to give more details