# How to wait return statement if subscriber not completed in angular 2/4/6

Tags: angular, publish-subscribe, angular6, adal, angular-observable

Currently I am working on the Angular6 project, and I have auth-http-interceptor. The problem in this file is that I want to get refresh token/acquire token from angular4-adal service every time, and for that, I have to subscribe the acquire token which will give the token and then want to assign that token in authReq object.

But my intercept method's return type is Observable.

Then how could I wait for subscribing the acquire token and then return next.handle(authReq).
I have tried to write the below code, but its throwing an error => **A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.**

> auth-http-interceptor.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private adalService: AdalService, private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.adalService.acquireToken('###myTenantId').subscribe((token) => {
            this.loaderService.display(true);
            const authReq = req.clone({
                url: environment.apiUrl + req.url,
                headers: req.headers
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            });
        return next.handle(authReq).finally(() => this.loaderService.display(false));
        });
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot return from `subscribe`. Instead you could use `flatMap`.

Comment: It is not working. Same error ocurring. I have used this.adalService.acquireToken('###myTenantId').flatMap((token) => {

Comment: sorry, you need to put `return` in front. `return this.adalService.acquireToken( .....`

Comment: No. it says Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` and also you cannot return anything from `subscribe`. You could use `flatMap` to first fetch the token, and then return the request, also re-place your `finally` and you should have some kind of error handler as well:

```ts
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.adalService.acquireToken('###myTenantId').flatMap((token) => {
        this.loaderService.display(true);
        const authReq = req.clone({
            url: environment.apiUrl + req.url,
            headers: req.headers
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        });
      return next.handle(authReq);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // error handling here
      return Observable.throw(err)
    })
    .finally(() => this.loaderService.display(false));
}
```

Comment: its working, but catch condition throwing error. if i do   .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
it throws an error => Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: `return Observable.throw(err)`

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :) :) Have a nice day and happy coding!

Comment: Hi  @AJT_82, could you please look once my another question on angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554591/type-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-type-observableinput