# How to return boolean value from a function that subscribes to an observable of another function?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, angular5, observable

I'm having this problem, I have a `ProductService` that has a boolean function `validateProductsBeforeChanges`.

Inside `validateProductsBeforeChanges` I call a function from another service called `OrderService` which returns an observable.

Some example code:

```
validateProductsBeforeChanges(idProduct): Boolean {
     this._orderService.getAll()
         .subscribe(orders => {
               this.orders = orders;
               this.ordersWithCurrentMenu = this.orders.filter(x => 
                                                               x.products.find(y => y.code == idProduct));

               if(this.ordersWithCurrentMenu.length > 0) {
                   return false;
               }
               else {
                   return true;
               }
         });
}
```

The problem is that vs code throws a syntax error:

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

So I tried doing something like this:

```
validateProductsBeforeChanges(idProduct): Boolean {
     this._orderService.getAll()
         .subscribe(orders => {
              this.orders = orders;
              this.ordersWithCurrentMenu = this.orders.filter(x => x.products.find(y => y.code == idProduct));

              if (this.ordersWithCurrentMenu.length > 0) {
                  return false;
              }
              else {
                  return true;
              }
         });

    return false;
}
```

But in that case, the last return gets executed before the `.subcribe` ends and the function always returns false.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Change `.subscribe(` to `.pipe(map(` with map coming from “rxjs/operators”. And add a return in front of everything. What ever is consuming this will need to subscribe instead. Return type would change to `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 how to return data from subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295854/angular-2-how-to-return-data-from-subscribe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
validateProductsBeforeChanges(idProduct): Observable<Boolean>{
  return this._orderService.getAll()
  .pipe(
      map(orders => 
       orders.filter(x => x.products.find(y => y.code == idProduct))
             .map(filtered => filtered <= 0)
      )          
   );
}
```

Use like this:

```
validateProductsBeforeChanges(id).subscribe(t=> {
     if (t) {
        ...
     }
     else {
       ...
     }
})
```